# Processing - show one circle at a time

Tags: processing, geometry

I have written this code which, on a mouse button press, increases or decreases the number of circles visible, equally spaced around a circle.

```
int nbr_circles = 2;
void setup() {    
  size(600, 600);

  smooth();
  background(255);
} 

void draw() { 
  background(255);
  float cx = width/2.0;
  float cy = height/2.0;
  fill(0);
  //float x, y; //  
  for (int i = 0; i < nbr_circles; i++) 
  {
    float angle = i * TWO_PI / nbr_circles;
    float x = cx + 110.0 * cos(angle);                
    float y = cy + 110.0 * sin(angle);                
    ellipse(x, y, 20, 20);
  }
}

void mousePressed() {

  if (mouseButton == LEFT) {
    if (nbr_circles < 20)
    nbr_circles = nbr_circles + 1;

  } else if (mouseButton == RIGHT) {
    if (nbr_circles > 2) 
      nbr_circles = nbr_circles - 1;

  }
}
```

I would like to alter the code so that, with nbr_circles fixed at 10, only one circle is visible at a time, each in turn in successive frames.

I have changed the code a little. The mouse buttons do nothing and the nbr_circles is fixed at 10.

**How can I now show one circle at a time?**

show circle #1 ->  hide circle #1, show circle #2 ->  hide circle #2, show circle #3 … -> hide circle #9, show circle #10 -> hide circle #1, show circle #1…

Adjusted code - where is it going wrong?

```
int nbr_circles = 2;
int i = 1;
void setup () {
  size (600, 600);
}

void draw () {
  background (255);
  fill (0);
  float cx = width/2.0;
  float cy = height/2.0;
  float angle = i * TWO_PI / nbr_circles;
  float x = cx + 110.0 * cos(angle);                
    float y = cy + 110.0 * sin(angle);                
    ellipse(x, y, 20, 20);
}

if (mouseButton == LEFT) {
  if (ellipse(x,y,20,20))
  rotate (angle);
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Really, I want to do the reverse of this, showing only one shape at a time.

http://www.rpdms.com/satillusion/saturation%20illusionc.gif

Answer (score -1):

Taking a step back, I really suggest you start a bit smaller, instead of posting a new question every time you get stuck. It looks like you've got a fundamental misunderstanding of the basic syntax of Processing, so maybe you should go back and do some tutorials until you're more comfortable in it. That's probably the most "correct" answer I can give you, even though it's probably not what you're looking for.

To answer the question of why your adjusted code doesn't work, it's because none of the syntax makes sense. First of all, you've got an if statement outside of a function, which isn't valid. When do you expect that if statement to be executed?

Secondly, you've got the ellipse() function inside an if statement, but the ellipse() function doesn't return a boolean. What do you expect that to do? And finally, what do you expect that rotate function to do?

It seems like you're trying to copy-paste code you found on the internet without really understanding any of it. That's not going to work. You have to take a step back and understand the basics before you can expect to make a program that actually does what you want it to do.

If you edit your "adjusted code" to fix the problems I pointed out, I'll try to help you through the process, but you really should consider going back and starting smaller before trying to get somebody else's code you found on the internet to work.